# How to create a smart contract which will execute everyday at the same hour?

Tags: multiversx

The title is pretty explanatory. I want a batch which will execute everyday, at the same hour. Like a batch.

Also, is it possible to have a smart contract with endpoints and batch executing inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to schedule a smart contract execution inside a smart contract.

Meaning if you want to call a function in the smart contract you have to send a transaction to the smart contract. To achieve this at the same time everyday you would have to use something like a cronjob on a traditional backend.

Not sure what you mean with endpoints and batch executing, but you can also make read only functions using the `#[view]` makro, instead of the `#[endpoint]` makro you would normally use for public functions. These view functions can be called without requiring a transaction using the `query` [endpoint](https://docs.elrond.com/sdk-and-tools/rest-api/virtual-machine/#compute-output-of-pure-function).

And of course you can use loops inside your smart contract to execute a bunch of things at the same time.